# Pyspark: Write Blank columns from a Dataframe as "None" when using Spark SFTP Package (Dataframe to CSV)

Tags: pyspark, pysftp, spark-sftp

```
    test_df.limit(10).repartition(1).write.format("com.springml.spark.sftp").\
        option("host", sftp_host).\
        option("username", sftp_user).\
        option("password", sftp_pass).\
        option("fileType", "csv"). \
        option("delimiter", "|"). \
        option("codec", "gzip"). \
        option("header", "false"). \
    save(f"/test/{file_date}_{file_name}.txt.gz")
```

The above code writes data in csv file in this format per row. (A|""|B|""|C) . However, I wish to write DataFrame as (A||B||C) where empty quotes are replaced with 'None' value.

Found a way to do in without using Spark SFTP package, but unable to figure out on how to use SPARK SFTP package and write "None" for blank columns.

Reference Docs: https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataFrame `na` function to replace any null or Nan values with the desired value

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "abc", "test"), (2, None, "test1")], ["col1", "col2", "col3"])
>>> df.show()
+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2| col3|
+----+----+-----+
|   1| abc| test|
|   2|null|test1|
+----+----+-----+

>>> df.na.fill("None", ["col2"]).show()
+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2| col3|
+----+----+-----+
|   1| abc| test|
|   2|None|test1|
+----+----+-----+
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill